# How to write variable type for map of objects in terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform-modules, terraform-variables

I am trying to write a variable type for below configuration

```
virtual_machines = {
  nodes = {
    app1_node1 = {
      "vm_name" = "app"
      "vm_num"  = "1"
      networks = {
        nic1 = {
          "nic_name" = "app-1"
          "subnet"   = "****"
        },
      }
    },
    service1_node1 = {
      "vm_name" = "service"
      "vm_num"  = "1"
      networks = {
        nic1 = {
          "nic_name" = "service-1"
          "subnet"   = "****"
        },
      }
    },
    db1_node1 = {
      "vm_name" = "db"
      "vm_num"  = "1"
      "as_name" = "app-avset"

      networks = {
        nic1 = {
          "nic_name" = "db-1-1"
          "subnet"   = "****"
        },
        nic2 = {
          "nic_name" = "db-1-2"
          "subnet"   = "/subscriptions/************/resourceGroups/pluto/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/pluto-infra/subnets/db-subnet"
        }
      }
    },
    db2_node2 = {
      "vm_name" = "db"
      "vm_num"  = "2"
      "as_name" = "app-avset"
      networks = {
        nic1 = {
          "nic_name" = "db-2-1"
          "subnet"   = "****"
        },
        nic2 = {
          "nic_name" = "db-2-2"
          "subnet"   = "/subscriptions/************/resourceGroups/pluto/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/pluto-infra/subnets/db-subnet"
        },
      }
    },
  }
}
```

I have tried with below variable type, however it is not working as expected.

```
variable "virtual_machines" {
  type = map(object({
    nodes = map(object({
      vm_name = string
      vm_num  = string
      as_name = optional(string)
      networks = map(object({
        nic_name = string
        subnet   = string
      }))
    }))
  }))
  default = {}
}
```

Error :

```
│ Error: Invalid value for input variable
│
│   on main.tf line 4, in module "virtualmachine":
│    4:   virtual_machines        = var.virtual_machines
│
│ The given value is not suitable for module.virtualmachine.var.virtual_machines declared at virtualmachine\variables.tf:6,1-28: element "nodes": attribute
│ "nodes" is required.
```

Could someone assist on how to write the correct type for the given configuration ? Note : The default should be empty if don't have requirement to create virtual machines.

Answer (score 2):

I do agree with `Olakunle Abiola`

The error you encountered was caused by an invalid structure in both **tfvars** and **variable**.

Here is the updated terraform code to create **VM**s using the **variable** and **tfvar** file.

**terraform.tfvars**

```
virtual_machines = {
  app1_node1 = {
    vm_name = "app"
    vm_num  = "1"
    networks = {
      nic1 = {
        nic_name = "/subscriptions/<sub-id>/resourceGroups/<RG_NAME>/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/NIC-2"
        subnet   = "****"
      }
    }
  },
  service1_node1 = {
    vm_name = "service"
    vm_num  = "1"
    networks = {
      nic1 = {
        nic_name = "/subscriptions/<>sub-id/resourceGroups/<RG_NAMe>/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/venkat-NIC-1"
        subnet   = "****"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**variables.tf**

```kotlin
    variable "virtual_machines" {
      description = "A map of virtual machine configurations"
      type = map(object({
        vm_name  = string
        vm_num   = string
        networks = map(object({
          nic_name = string
          subnet   = string
        }))
      }))
      default = {}
    }
```

**Main.tf**

```kotlin
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}
data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "<RG_Name>"
}
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "main" {
  for_each = var.virtual_machines
 
  name                  = "${each.value.vm_name}${each.value.vm_num}"
  location              = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name   = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  vm_size               = "Standard_DS1_v2"
 
  network_interface_ids = [for _, nic in each.value.networks : nic.nic_name]
 
  storage_image_reference {
    publisher = "Canonical"
    offer     = "0001-com-ubuntu-server-jammy"
    sku       = "22_04-lts"
    version   = "latest"
  }
 
  storage_os_disk {
    name              = "${each.value.vm_name}${each.value.vm_num}-osdisk"
    caching           = "ReadWrite"
    create_option     = "FromImage"
    managed_disk_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }
 
  os_profile {
    computer_name  = "${each.value.vm_name}${each.value.vm_num}"
    admin_username = "testadmin"
    admin_password = ""
  }
 
  os_profile_linux_config {
    disable_password_authentication = false
  }
 
  tags = {
    environment = "staging"
  }
}
```

**Terraform apply:**

[image]

After running the code, the `VMs` were successfully created in the **Azure portal**

[image]